# In python, using PIL or Pilllow, how can I take an image with a green backdrop, cut the green and move it to a new image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on a school project, where we have to take 2 images, one with a green backdrop, and another image of a landscape (i.e. a beach or field) and cut the green pixels of the green backdrop imag, so that we can take the image and place it on top of the background image in a new image file. For example, taking a cactus and placing it on a field, where the first picture of the cactus has a green backdrop. This should be through the iteration of pixels and using only pillow to finish. This is what I have so far:

Comment: You forgot to include your code - unless you want to tell us that you have nothing so far.